# How to use Gedmo nested tree for storing multiple trees in one single table?

Tags: symfony, tree, nested, stofdoctrineextensions

I have a table which store a tree for each username.
My entity looks like this:

```
/**
* Confsaves
* @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
* @ORM\Table(name="confsaves")
 *@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
 */
class Confsaves
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=200, nullable=true)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
 * @ORM\Column(name="Username", type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeParent
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Confsaves", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Confsaves", mappedBy="parent")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
 */
private $children;

/**
 * @var integer
 * 
 * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
 * @ORM\Column(name="lft", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $lft;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @Gedmo\TreeRight
 * @ORM\Column(name="rght", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $rght;


/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

I want build a different tree for each user.

In my controller I have created the repository like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Confsaves');
```

How can I set the scope of the repository only on the user connected?
Is level necessary for build tree function?

I use an existing database that only have left, right and parent arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has been a long time, but for the record:

If you want a tree for each user, you must establish a relationship between your `Confsaves` and `User` entities, more specifically, between the `root` property of your `Confsaves` entity and your `User` one. Doctrine Extensions supports relationships on the root property of your tree [since 2.4](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/850). Make sure you are using the right version. Cost me a day of debugging.

So, to relate your nested set tree to a user entity, just perform a `ManyToOne` in your User, and the inverse relationship in your Tree entity.